# Intercepting HTTP Requests using Chrome Console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to intercept requests sent by the website to a URL, but any method I try is only compatible with chrome extensions, puppeteer, selenium, etc.
Basically, what I'm asking is, is there a way to intercept HTTP requests without using any 3rd party tools and only the chrome console?